# Linq query using generics & interfaces

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

I have several entity framework classes that implement the following an IInactive interface.

```
public interface IInactive
{
    bool inactive { get; set; }
}
```

For example, my Order class is defined as follows:

```
public class Order : IInactive
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid orderId { get; set; }
    ...
    public bool inactive { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to implement a generic method that can be used against all objects (entities) whether they implement the IInactive interface or not. It would be called as follows:

```
var query = GetAllActive<Order>();
```

My code for this generic method looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetAllActive<T>() where T : class
{
    DbSet<T> dbSet = this._db.Set<T>();

    // Does the entity implement the IInactive interface.
    // If yes, only return "active" row, otherwise return all rows
    if (typeof(T)is IInactive)
    {
        // Problem: the code in this block never executes, that is,
        // (typeof(T)is IInactive) never evaluates to true

       ...

    }

    return dbSet;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate some help solving this issue! Thanks.

Comment: Start with `where T : class, IInactive` and see where that takes you. Even if it doesn't solve this exact problem, you can skip the implementation check and prevent callers from using entity types that don't support this check (it's enforced by the compiler and the runtime!).

Comment: Thanks, but I actually want to be able to call this method for all entities, even those that do not implement IInactive.  If the class does not implement IInactive, I want to return all records.

Comment: I have an idea but I have to test it to make sure it'll work. If it works and you don't have an answer yet, I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks madreflection, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (typeof(T) is IInactive)
```

try

```
if (typeof(IInactive).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
```

Comment: Tom - Thanks that did the trick on the first issue.  That's a new one for me.  Any ideas on how to cast IQueryable<IInactive> to IQueryable<T>? Thanks!

Comment: @BillHaack this is a completely different question

Comment: Fair enough, I edited the question to just include the 1st issue.  I will create a second post for for the other issue.